# Inner Product for Functions

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that **f** = $f(x)$ and **g** = $g(x)$ are two continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[a,b]$.
In other words, they are in the vector space $C($[$a,b]$
,$\mathbb R$) of continuous real valued functions defined on [$a$,$b$].

Show that an inner product on $C($[$a,b]$
,$\mathbb R$) can be defined as:

$\langle f, g\rangle=\int^{b}_{a}f(x)g(x)dx$

To be honest, I have no idea where to start. Would it be possible to provide hints and some guidance as to how I should approach this?

Comment: Hint: The space of continuous functions is a subspace of the Hilbert space $L^2([a,b],\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: i think you just have to check that the conditions of $\langle,\rangle$ to be an inner product are indeed fulfilled. Start for example with linearity that is quite easy...

Comment: @JanoKakara In view of the level of the question, I conjecture that the OP has never heard of $L^2$, so your comment won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Check that all the conditions of inner product valid, use the integral properties,
for example:
$\langle \alpha f,g \rangle = \int_a^b (\alpha f)(x)g(x)dx = \int_a^b \alpha f(x)g(x)dx =  \alpha  \int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = \alpha \langle f,g \rangle$.

to prove the part that $\langle f,f \rangle = 0$ iff $f=0$, use that if $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ then $\int_a^b f(x)dx > \int_a^bg(x)dx$, and non-negative function integral equal $0$ over some interval iff the function equal to $0$ in that interval.

Comment: Well you should point out, that the nontrivial part is to proof that $\langle f,f\rangle=0$ iff $f=0$

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that if $f$ is a positive real valued continuous function then $\int_a^b f=0 \iff f=0$.(See below):

> Proof:Suppose  that $f\neq 0$ .Then suppose that $\exists x $ such that $f(x)=c>0$.Since $f$ is continuous at $x$ ;corressponding to $\epsilon =\dfrac{c}{2}; \exists \delta >0$   such that $f(x)\in (\dfrac{c}{2},\dfrac{3c}{2}) \forall x\in (c-\delta,c+\delta )$.
>
> Thus $\int_a^b f>\int _{c-\delta } ^{c+\delta }f>c\delta>0$.Hence a contradiction.Thus $f=0$

Now use this fact to show that $\int_a^b f^2=\langle f,f\rangle =0\iff f=0$