# Is there an inner product on $\mathcal{C}(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Is there an inner product on the vector space of continuous real functions $\mathcal{C}(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$ ? If so what is it and if not why ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1466878/inner-product-for-functions?rq=1

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough it is about function from R to R I will edit

Comment: thanks for your consideration

Comment: It seems clear that the usual "integral" inner product won't work.  Of course, no inner product induces the usual topology on $C(\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$, which is given by the sup norm.

Comment: Question is answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814754/inner-product-on-c-mathbb-r.  Yes with the Axiom of Choice, using a Hamel basis.  But no "explicit" form possible--it's consistent with ZF that no inner product exists.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The usual topology on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is not normable. There are of course plenty of non-equivalent inner products on every infinite-dimensional real (or complex) vector space, but for spaces like $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, one needs quite a lot of choice for that. It is consistent with dependent choice that **no norm** exists on that space, and a fortiori no inner product.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for that